# Execute command in new window with Ant from IDEA

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA I have this task in my Ant script

```
<target name="emulator-logcat">
    <exec command="adb" spawn="false" osfamily="windows">
        <arg value="-e"/>
        <arg value="shell"/>
        <arg value="logcat"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

It works but command output sent to IDEA ant window, not in Windows console window. How i can forward command output into new Windows console window as if i start this command from cmd.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved:
I create `runner.bat` file witch contains `%*` and call it like this

```
<target name="emulator-logcat">
    <exec command="cmd.exe" spawn="true" osfamily="windows">
        <arg line="/c start runner.bat adb -e shell logcat"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: can you tell us how your runner.bat file looks ?